# Error while invoking worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

```
<displayName>RSSReader</displayName>
<description>RSSReader</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>www.engadget.com</domain>
        <port>8080</port>
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getFeeds" />

<procedure name="getFeedsFiltered" />
```

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure 
>   [project WorklightAdaptersProject]RSSReader/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E: 
>   parameters: [project WorklightAdaptersProject] Http request failed:
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
>   http://www.engadget.com:8080 refused FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project
>   WorklightAdaptersProject]org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
>   Connection to http://www.engadget.com:8080 refused 
>                                                                                                                  com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve from that (RSS  / Webservices)?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the port set to `8080`?
It should be `80`.  Then it should work.

Even if trying to load the website with `8080` it fails.
Try `80`.